# Meteor app loosing international character encoding

Tags: templates, meteor, encoding

I have got a problem encoding international characters inside meteor templates. What's strange the non-template parts /like title or static html/ do render properly.
Made tests using FlowRouter and Iron:router, tried to inject UTF-8 meta etc - the same results ... 
Files are UTF-8 encoded for sure, Windows desktop env, RedHat OpenShift hosting (but localhost:3000 acts the same).

Do I miss something ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse default html file encoding is other then UTF-8 ... I checked twice, but js files. Had no idea there are separate options based on extension ...
Solution: check both js and html file encoding within your IDE :)